# Getting transaction count from RPC with Flashbots provider and signers results in hex > 64 bits error. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, smartcontracts

Error: Processing response error(body="{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":44,"error":{"code":-32602,"message\ ":"invalid argument 1: hex > 64 bits"}}", error={"code":-32602}, requestBody="{"method":"eth_getTransactionCount","params":["\0xbb2f031ba8e4054c6deb595e0cc8a0350355c85","0xbb2f031ba8e4054c6deb595e0cc8a0350355c85"],"id":44,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}", requestMethod ="POST", url="https://rpc.ankr.com/eth/60aa9cfcf046ce2599df4fd3fc5800ff8dbb4eab9ac032ae99f13e07ad66ffcc", code=SERVER_ERROR, version-web/5.7.1)
at Logger.makeError (D:\NFT Projects\The Accountant\The-Accountant\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
at Logger.throwError (D:\NFT Projects\The Accountant\The-Accountant\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
at D:\NFT Projects\The Accountant\The-Accountant\node_modules@ethersproject\web\src.ts\index.ts:341:28
at step (D:\NFT Projects\The Accountant\The-Accountant\node_modules@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
at Object.next(D:\NFT Projects\The Accountant\The-Accountant\node_modules@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
at fulfilled (D:\NFT Projects\The Accountant\The-Accountant\node_modules@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
at processTicksAndRejections(node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

I'm trying to set up the flashbots provider with signers, but I keep getting errors.
I'll share a screenshot of the error below. But basically I'm trying to get the transaction count from RPC, but I can't seem to do that.

Excuse the confusion of provider js.

tried a lot

The error in the screenshot is from the transaction function on line 53 after signing, but there are a few other issues that I believe may be related to the ethers js. But I'm not too sure.

Comment: Hi. Please format your code using "`" symbol.